# MS Access - 2021 Syntax Error on button "ADD"

Tags: javascript, sql

I really need any helper for my coding below..this is for my final year project. I using form design and subform. when I try to click add it shows a Syntax Error. I was follow coding from Youtube.. Thank you for your Help

```js
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO Register(ID,MRN,Patient Name,IC,PKRC,Location,Date)"& _
"VALUES(" & Me.txtID &",'" & Me.txtMRN & "','" & _
Me.txtName &"','" & Me.txtIC &"','" & Me.cobPKRC &"','" & Me.cobLocation &"','" & Me.txtHari&"')


 Else
    'Otherwise the data will be updated
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Register]" & _
    "SET ID =" & Me.txtID & _
    ", MRNe='" & Me.txtMRN & "'" & _
    ", Patient Name='" & Me.txtName & "'" & _
    ", IC='" & Me.txtIC & "'" & _
    ", PKRC='" & Me.cobPKRC & "'" & _
    ", Location ='" & Me.cobLocation & "'" & _
    ", Date ='" & Me.txtHari & "'" & _
    "WHERE ID =" & Me.txtID.Tag


    End If


   cmdClear_Click

frmRegisterSub.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript? The code seems to be Visual Basic. It's definitely not JavaScript.

Comment: I'd suggest storing the SQL text in a variable and outputting it with `Debug.Print sqlText` so you can see what you've built. However, I'll think you'll find there is at least an error relating to the closing bracket for the insert values. That bracket should be part of your string and therefore should be followed by a (closing) quote mark.